# Properly align text in description

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, indentation, description

I need to illustrate cases, that is why I am using the description environment:

```
\begin{description}
\item[Caso 1] Esiste una computazione $s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_k$ di $\mathcal P$ che comincia con l'istantanea iniziale. Scriviamo allora $\psi^{(m)}_{\mathcal P}(r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_m)$ per indicare il valore della variabile $Y$ al raggiungimento dell'istantanea terminale $s_k$.
\item[Caso 2] Non esiste una tale computazione. Ad esempio esiste una sequenza non finita $s_1, s_2, s_3, \ldots$ che parte con l'istantanea iniziale, ed ogni $s_{i+1}$ è la successiva di $s_i$, inoltre in tali casi $\psi^{(m)}_{\mathcal P}(r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_m)$ è \emph{indefinita}.
\end{description}
```

but the thing is the text isn't properly aligned as my screenshot shows:
[image]

so my question is: how do I fix this?

Comment: I don't see a misalignment. What do you take issue with?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Im not sure if this is what you want, but i consider you want it with straight margins like this:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item[\textbf{Caso 1}] Esiste una computazione $s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_k$ di $\mathcal P$ che comincia con l'istantanea iniziale. Scriviamo allora $\psi^{(m)}_{\mathcal P}(r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_m)$ per indicare il valore della variabile $Y$ al raggiungimento dell'istantanea terminale $s_k$.
    \item[\textbf{Caso 2}]Non esiste una tale computazione. Ad esempio esiste una sequenza non finita $s_1, s_2, s_3, \ldots$ che parte con l'istantanea iniziale, ed ogni $s_{i+1}$ è la successiva di $s_i$, inoltre in tali casi $\psi^{(m)}_{\mathcal P}(r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_m)$ è \emph{indefinita}.
\end{itemize}
```

[image]

Using `itemize` instead of `description` solves your alignment problem.

Comment: First of all thank you for the answer, the problem with this solution is that the bolded text goes beyond the margins set for the regular paragraphs.

Comment: You could use the `enumitem` package and define your own margins for this list. `\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=5em]`

Comment: Using `enumitem` you could also use an option like `style=nextline`. To set the margin to the length of the longest item (let's say it' "Caso 2"), use `labelwidth=\widthof{\bfseries Caso 2}`.

Answer (score 1):

Given the output from the previous answer, I would use the [`enumitem`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem) package for this, either using an `enumerate` environment with local settings

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=Caso \arabic*,font=\bfseries]
    \item Esiste una ...
    \item Non esiste una...
\end{enumerate}
```

or else using your own custom list

```
\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[mylist]{label=Caso \arabic*,font=\bfseries}
...
\begin{mylist}
    \item Esiste una ...
    \item Non ...
\end{mylist}
```

They both produce the same output, but with a less manual input process.

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[mylist]{label=Caso \arabic*,font=\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=Caso \arabic*,font=\bfseries]
    \item Esiste una computazione $s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_k$ di $\mathcal P$ che comincia con l'istantanea iniziale. Scriviamo allora $\psi^{(m)}_{\mathcal P}(r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_m)$ per indicare il valore della variabile $Y$ al raggiungimento dell'istantanea terminale $s_k$.
    \item Non esiste una tale computazione. Ad esempio esiste una sequenza non finita $s_1, s_2, s_3, \ldots$ che parte con l'istantanea iniziale, ed ogni $s_{i+1}$ è la successiva di $s_i$, inoltre in tali casi $\psi^{(m)}_{\mathcal P}(r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_m)$ è \emph{indefinita}.
\end{enumerate}

Your own list
\begin{mylist}
    \item Esiste una computazione $s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_k$ di $\mathcal P$ che comincia con l'istantanea iniziale. Scriviamo allora $\psi^{(m)}_{\mathcal P}(r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_m)$ per indicare il valore della variabile $Y$ al raggiungimento dell'istantanea terminale $s_k$.
    \item Non esiste una tale computazione. Ad esempio esiste una sequenza non finita $s_1, s_2, s_3, \ldots$ che parte con l'istantanea iniziale, ed ogni $s_{i+1}$ è la successiva di $s_i$, inoltre in tali casi $\psi^{(m)}_{\mathcal P}(r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_m)$ è \emph{indefinita}.
\end{mylist}
\end{document}
```